# not able to configure a provider with token in angular without defining the string

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a provider in the module as shown below but getting an error saying that MY_TOKEN is not defined. Is it necessary to put quotes around this literal as I think that following code snippet is legal. Does it  have to be an import or a string constant if I have to use it. Will it not automatically treat MY_TOKEN as a string literal?

```
 providers: [{provide : MY_TOKEN, useValue:'dfd'},
```

Comment: It's just plain TypeScript. MY_TOKEN needs to be a constant defined somewhere. And it should be of type `InjectionToken<string>`. See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#non-class-dependencies

Comment: @JBNizet ok. will check. was thinking the same